# Is it possible to get two different relation times between two nodes in Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

I am new to Galaxybase and I'm playing around with it to learn more.

If I create two nodes in the space and establish a relationship between them, along with a timestamp indicating when they became friends, can I retrieve two different timestamps for the same relationship if I set the direction as "no" and only create the relationship once? Can you provide an example of how this might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, you could create a graph model such as:

```
person - degree of relationship - person
```

The "Person" is the name of the vertex and the "Degree of Relationship" is the name of the edge. The Edge can be set with the following properties：degree, time, place, etc.

The "degree" can be set to STRING type, and the content can be set to: met, known, in love, married, divorced, etc. And set the corresponding time in "time" property.